# How to use onChange() function for sorting?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please check my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qNFe3Py704BU4aYriiZ9?p=preview) 
It is working fine when i am using buttons but I want same functionality with the dropdown.

Please explain me how to write `onChange()` or edit the plunk

code:
html:
`<select ng-options="d for d in opt2" ng-model="varun" ng-change="onchange()">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
    </select>`

js:

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
      $scope.friends = orderBy($scope.friends, predicate, reverse);
    };

    $scope.varun = $scope.opt2[0];
   $scope.onchange = function() {
alert($scope.varun);
if($scope.varun == age2 )
{
   $scope.friends = orderBy($scope.friends, 'age' , false);
}
else
{
  $scope.order('-date',true);
}
  }
  }
```

Comment: i gave link for plunk and i got the answer also

Comment: The post is not for you only. If the link will die, future visitors don't have any clue what is your question. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok.. thank you.. I am editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look at console it says

> ReferenceError: age2 is not defined

you need to write bellow

```
if($scope.varun == 'age2' )
```

instead of

```
if($scope.varun == age2 )
```